# Cannot load style sheet in WAMP

Tags: css, wamp

I have some views in my enviroment, and I link those views with some style sheets in the usual way, like this for example:

```
<link href="../../public/css/basics2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

My situation is that when I run my web page from the WAMP this doesnt load the style sheet... 
but If I just copy the whole proyect in my desktop and open the index, it does load the Stylesheet...

Any idea?

Comment: Using browser view-source: you can click on that css file link and see what absolute path it is pointing to. You can debug it from there..

Comment: check the apache error console

Answer (score 0):

I know the reason why... It's because I am a newbie.

When one configures the WAMP to look at the "public" the routes need to refer to the public folder... so those ../../ are not necesary... this is what works>

```
<link href="css/basics2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

And using blade:

```
{{ HTML::style('css/basics2.css') }}
```